# Can Watson R&R service specify whether specific user can access to restricted answer?

Tags: ibm-watson, watson, retrieve-and-rank

As I know, Watson can provide relatively right answer with rank-confidence once user asks their question. But in real world, some restricted information must not be opened to every user.
Can Watson learn about which answer must not be opened to public or who can access to restricted answer? If possible, how to make Watson learning?

Answer (score 2):

The service won't provide that for you out of the box.

You could add that at an application level, though. For example, you could modify the schema to include an additional field describing who should be able to access that document. Then when you store documents in the Solr index, add that field...

```
{
    "id" : "12345",
    "title" : "Super secret doc",
    "body" : "Shh... don't tell anyone about this...", 
    ...

    "role" : "uber-user",
    ...

}
```

Then in your queries to the service, you can include a value for the role parameter, so that only documents that have role set to "uber-user" are returned.

It might be easier to make that numeric, describing the access level needed to access a document. e.g. documents that anyone can access get `accesslevel` of 0, documents that are private get `accesslevel` set to 10, and super secret documents have `accesslevel` of 20.

```
{
    "id" : "12345",
    "title" : "Super secret doc",
    "body" : "Shh... don't tell anyone about this...", 
    ...

    "accesslevel" : 20,
    ...

}
```

A query for a high-level user could include a query parameter for `accesslevel <= 20` and get all the documents, sensitive or not.
A query for a low-level user would have query parameter of `accesslevel <= 0` and only get the public ones.

I'm sure there are lots of other ways to approach it - those are just two quick ideas off the top of my head.

But in summary, R&R won't do this for you, but there is enough flexibility in what you store and how you prepare your queries that you should be able to add this for yourself.